# How do I check that user inputs certain string?

Tags: jquery

Maybe this code ain't great, but how do you check that the user inputted one of 4 acceptable values: (1) Banana, (2) Bigby's Crushing Hand spell, (3). Bag of gold, or (4) Crossbow?

```
function whatYouFound(){
    var stuff = ["1. Banana<P>", "2. Bigby's Crushing Hand spell<P>", "3. Bag of gold<P>", "4. Crossbow<P>"];
    var a = "The orc moves in and takes an item of yours.";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = stuff.join("") + a;
    $('#choiceBB').show();
};

function chooseOne(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput2').value;

    if ($.trim($("#userInput2").val()) === "") {
        alert('You did not fill in anything');
        return false;
    }
    else {document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = 'He took your ' + userInput + ". That's embarassing.";
    $('#choiceCC').show();
    };
};
```

Comment: <P> will be seen as an unclosed paragraph tag...

Comment: What is the user inputting?

Comment: Good point on the <P>. Right now when user clicks, they can enter anything. I want the only acceptable inputs to be one of the 4 listed items, otherwise return an alert.

Comment: what are they entering? the number? the text?

Comment: The text, ideally.

Comment: So it is either indexOf or loop over and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the indexOf method. This method will return the array position if ot finds a match. See here for further reference. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp